# Representing Integers as Functions (Church Numerals?)

Tags: haskell, miranda

Given the following function definition and assuming similar definitions for all positive integers give the type definition and code for a function called plus that will take as arguments two such functions representing integers and return a function that represents the sum of the two input integers. E.g. `(plus one two)` should evaluate to a function that takes two arguments `f x` and returns `(f(f(f x)))`.

```
one f x = f x
two f x = f (f x)
three f x = f (f (f x)))
```

etc.

I am new to functional programming and I can't get my head around this. I firstly don't know how I can define the functions for all the positive integers without writing them out (which is obviously impossible). As in, if I have `plus(sixty, forty)`, how can my function recognize that sixty is f applied 60 times to `x`?

I am meant to be writing this in Miranda, but I am more familiar with Haskell, so help for either is welcome.

Comment: A good way to _test_ this is to make a function increments (like `++`) and then create a test harness that passes an initial value (`0`) and the increment function in place of `f`.

Comment: As for your `plus` function, you should be thinking about creating a function that _adds_ function applications. (So, think wrap one in the other).

Comment: I still don't understand. Do I need to convert sixty (for example) to 60? Is there a built in function for that?

Comment: No, you don't want to convert.  You want to build up church numerals.  But, you can test the structure that you have created afterword.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apply equational reasoning<sup>1</sup>, and *abstraction*. You have

```
one   f x =       f x                       -- :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
two   f x =    f (f x)   -- = f (one f x)   -- :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
three f x = f (f (f x))  -- = f (two f x)   -- :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
--                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Thus, a *successor* function `next` is naturally defined, so that `three = next two`. Yes, it is as simple as writing `next two` instead of `three` in the equation above:

```
next :: ((b -> c) -> a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
-- three f x = next two f x = f (two f x)   -- `two` is a formal parameter
--                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
next                num f x = f (num f x)   -- generic name `num`

zero :: t -> a -> a
zero f x = x
```

This captures the pattern of succession. `f` will be used as a *successor* function, and `x` as *zero* value. The rest follows. For instance,

```
plus :: (t -> b -> c) -> (t -> a -> b) -> t -> a -> c
plus two one f x = two f (one f x)   -- formal parameters two, one
              -- = f (f (one f x))   -- an example substitution
              -- = f (f (f x)        --   uses the global definitions
              -- = three f x         --   for one, two, three
```

i.e. `one f x` will be used as a zero value by `two` (instead of the "usual" `x`), thus representing *`three`*. A "number" `n` represents a succession of *n* `+1` operations.

The above, again, actually defines the general `plus` operation because `two` and `one` are just two formal function parameters:

```
Prelude> plus three two succ 0    -- built-in `succ :: Enum a => a -> a`
5
Prelude> :t plus three two
plus three two :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
Prelude> plus three two (1:) [0]
[1,1,1,1,1,0]
```

The key thing to gasp here is that a function is an object that *will* produce a value, when called. In itself it's an opaque object. The "observer" arguments that we apply to it, supply the "meaning" for what it means to be zero, or to find a successor, and thus define what result is produced when we make an observation of a number's value.

<sup>1</sup>*i.e. replace freely in any expression the LHS with the RHS of a definition, or the RHS with the LHS, as you see fit (up to the variables renaming of course, to not capture/shadow the existing free variables).*

Comment: thank you. could you help me with the type definition for the function, I am still struggling to implement it so perhaps that would help me get my head around it

Comment: it's very simple you just ask GHCi about it: `:t let one f x = f x in one` produces `:: (t -> t1) -> t -> t1`. And for `plus` it is  `:: (t -> t1 -> t2)
-> (t -> t3 -> t1)
-> t
-> t3
-> t2` We can freely replace the `t_i` with `a,b,c,d,...` for readability.

Comment: what is it that you're struggling to implement? The above definitions just go, as they are, right into your source code file.

Answer (score 5):

To convert a number to a numeral you can use something like:

```
type Numeral = forall a . (a -> a) -> (a -> a)

toChurch :: Int -> Numeral
toChurch 0 _ x = x
toChurch n f x = f $ toChurch (pred n) f x

fromChurch :: Numeral -> Int
fromChurch numeral = numeral succ 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to recognize how many times the function is calling `f`. For example, to implement `succ`, which adds 1 to a Church numeral, you can do something like this:

```
succ n f x = f (n f x)
```

Then you first use `n` to apply `f` however many times it needs to, and then you do the final `f` yourself. You could also do it the other way round, and first apply `f` once yourself and then let `n` do the rest.

```
succ n f x = n f (f x)
```

You can use a similar technique to implement `plus`.

Comment: but how do I get n? say I have (plus one two) then how do I get (plus (1 f x) (2 f x))?

Comment: so say i had two church numerals represented as 1 f x and 2 f x. Could i just say that their sum was (1+2) f x?

Comment: @user3391947: `n` here is just a Church numeral. So you could say `three f x = succ two f x`, or just `three = succ two`.

Comment: this shadows the built-in `succ`.